# User-agent feature projection with caniuse?

Tags: html, node.js

Is there a standard way or module that can allow me to check the user agent against caniuse to predict feature support with a reasonable level of certainty?

e.g.
**Does browser X, version Y support a, b, c, etc. or all of HTML5?**

I've tried to implement something which uses https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js and https://github.com/fyrd/caniuse but I'm having trouble understanding exactly how to ask caniuse for this information.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, [search NPM for your area of interest](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=caniuse). The answer is, yes, there is a module...take your pick.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you like to do that on the server side?

On client side, there is a great Modernizr library: http://modernizr.com/